# Best way to run a function when page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call a function when the page is refreshed. I adding a state if the page is rendered with the data I got from my backend end but I get an warning message "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state." Even though it works fine (except with the warning message), I dont think this is the best, most efficient way to do it?

If this is the best, most efficient way, how do I fix the waring message?

```js
function Demo() {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      username: "unknown",
      rendered: false,
    }
    this.renderUserProfile = this.renderUserProfile.bind(this);
  }

  update(){
    //code to retrieve data from backend node.js *
    this.setState({ username: data });
    this.setState({ rendered: true });
  }

  render(){
    if (!this.state.rendered) {
      this.update();
    }
    return (<p>demo</p>)
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do never change state inside `render`, because every state (or prop) change will call `render` again. That is what the warning is telling you: you risk having infinite loops.

There is no need of a state param for "rendered", because your component will call `render` anyway as soon as `this.setState({username: data});` executes. If you want something to happen then, add it in `update` just after the setState line.

Now let's imagine that you still really want it. If you don't want your component to render when the `rendered` state changes, then just don't use the React Component state, but any standard class attribute:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    rendered = false
    ...
    render() {
        this.rendered = true
        ....
    }
}
```

Just be aware that this looks super wrong (and useless) since it tries to go around what the React framework is good at.

Finally, from this code there is no way to know how you intend you have new data coming in. If it is an Ajax call, then you will call `this.update` with that data in the callback of your Ajax call - certainly not in `render`.